# UINavigationBar is too tall when using UIViewController containment and showing/hiding the status bar

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout, statusbar

My app is set up where the root view controller uses [UIViewController containment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) to present the main content of the app (which is common if you have a [side menu in your app](https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu)). I created this view controller via a storyboard using Auto Layout.

Whenever my status bar is hidden and then shown (e.g. like when I view a YouTube video in my app), the navigation bar appears too tall (it's as though the status bar is reporting its height as being double than what it actually is).

Which looks similar to the following:

[image]

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was aligning the UIContainerView to the Top Layout Guide's **Bottom**. If you switch the constraint to be pinned to the Superview's Top, or to the **Top** of the Top Layout Guide, you should get correct behavior in both iOS 7 and 8.

---

For reference, here is what happens when you attempt align to different objects:

```
+-------------------------+-----+------------+-----------------+
|       Aligned To        | iOS | Visibility |  Result (Image) |
+-------------------------+-----+------------+-----------------+
| Superview.Top           | *   | *          | Correct (1 & 2) |
| Top Layout Guide.Top    | *   | *          | Correct (1 & 2) |
| Top Layout Guide.Bottom | 7   | Hidden     | Bug (3)         |
| Top Layout Guide.Bottom | 7   | Visible    | Bug (4 or 5)    |
| Top Layout Guide.Bottom | 8   | Hidden     | Correct (1)     |
| Top Layout Guide.Bottom | 8   | Visible    | Bug (4 or 5)    |
+-------------------------+-----+------------+-----------------+
```

Notes: `*` in the *iOS* column refers to iOS 7 and 8. `*` in the *Visibility* column refers to hidden and visible.

## Images:

### 1: Correctly Hidden

> [image]
> (Status bar is completely removed.)

### 2: Correctly Shown

> [image]

### 3: Incorrectly Hidden

> [image]
> (Status bar height is retained, but nothing is shown there.)

### 4: Incorrectly Shown

> [image]
> (The status bar gets a white background, and there is extra space as though it is double its height.)

### 5: Incorrectly Shown (Initially)

> [image]
> (The status bar has a white background, but the height is correct. This seems to happen only the first time when the app launches and the status bar is shown. After hiding and showing the status bar a second time, it will look like #4.)